# Copy Every thing after a regex is matched

Tags: c#, regex

i have to create a function `GetSourceCodeOfClass("ClassName",FilePath)` this function will be used more than 10000 times to get  Srouce code from c#  Files, and from every source file i have to extract the source code of a complete class i.e

> " Class someName { **every thing in the body including sinature**} "

Now this is simple, if a single file contains a single class but there will be many source files that will contain more than two classes in them , further more the bigger problem is there maybe nested classes inside a single class.

i want following thing :-

- i want to extract the complete source of a given Class
- if file contains more than two classes then i want to extract only the source code of  specified class.
- if  file contains more than  one class  and  my specified class have nested classes in it then i want to capture myClasses's source as well as all nested classes.

i have an algorithm in mid that is:
1-open file
2-match regex (C# classes signature ) - parameterized

> @"(public|private|internal|protected|inline)?[\t ]*(static)?[\t
>   ]*class[\t ]*" + **sOurClassName** + @"(([\t ]*[:][\t ]*([a-zA-z]+(([
>   ]*)[,]([ ]*)\w+)*)+))?\s*[\n\r\t\s]?{"

3- If Regex is matched in the source file 
4 Start copying at that point until the same regex is matched again but without parameters 
regex is:

> @" (public|private|internal|protected)?[\t ]*(static)?[\t ]*class[\t
>   ]*\w+(([\t ]*[:][\t ]*([a-zA-z]+(([ ]*)[,]([
>   ]*)\w+)*)+))?\s*[\n\r\t\s]?{"

(this is where i have no clue and i am stuck. I want to copy every thing after first matched to the second matched or after first match till the end )

copying nested classes is still an issue and i am still thinking about it if some one have an idea , can help me in this too.

Note- match.groups[0] or match.groups[1] this will only copy the signature but i want  the complete source of the class thats why i am doing this way . ..

BTW i am using C#

Comment: I have to wonder why you're using regexen for parsing instead of any of the various C# parsers available, including Roslyn.

Comment: Nathan thanks for pointing me towards parsers , actually  i Chooses Regex because they are easier than creating a complete new parser , and for Roslyn , i would be honest ,, i was unaware of it , will look into it   as in my project's latter stage i have to use parsers at least , at this moment i am trying to do maximum work with regex , anyways thanks . One More Request if someone have solved anything related to my problem using Roslyn , can you please point me to it. Especially Call Delegation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Nathan's sentiment that you would be better using an existing C#-aware parser. Trying to write a regex for the task is a lot of work, and you are unlikely to get it right on the first try. It may work on your first example code, or even the first few, but eventually you'll find some code that's slightly different than what you expected and the regex will fail to catch something important.

That said, if you are comfortable with that limitation and risk, the general technique you are asking about (if I understand correctly…the question isn't entirely clear) is common enough, and worth understanding if you expect to use regex a lot. The key points to understand are that with a `Match` object, you can call the `NextMatch()` method to obtain the next match in the next, and that when calling the `Regex.Match()` method, you can pass the start and length of a substring you want to check, and it will limit its processing to that substring.

You can use the latter point to switch from one regex to another mid-parse.

In your scenario, I understand it to be that you want to run a regex containing the specific class name, to find that particular class in the file, and then to search the text after the initial match for any subsequent class in the file. If the second search finds something, you want to only return the text from the start of the first match to the start of the second match. If the second search finds nothing, you want to return the text from the start of the first match to the end of the whole file.

If that's correct, then something like this should work:

```
string ExtractClass(string fileContents, Regex classRegex, Regex nonClassRegex)
{
    Match match1 = classRegex.Match(fileContents);

    if (!match1.Success)
    {
        return null;
    }

    Match match2 = nonClassRegex.Match(fileContents, match1.Index + match1.Length);

    if (!match2.Success)
    {
        return fileContents.Substring(match1.Index);
    }

    return fileContents.Substring(match1.Index, match2.Index - match1.Index);
}
```

I should note that between two class declarations, or between the end of a lone class declaration and the actual end of the file there can easily be other non-white-space text that isn't part of the class declaration. I assume you have a plan for dealing with that.

If the above doesn't address your need, you should examine your question closely, and edit it both for length and clarity.

Comment: Thanks Peter ,,, You provided exact solution to my problem , sure  i know about the limitation , and now  i will be  working on extending the solution to extract Nested classes as well ..... any help about extending this to extract nested classes as well  ? or if you think using Roslyn is easier in this matter please point me towards the solution ..

Comment: Nested classes are indeed harder (and a good reason to use a real parser). Unfortunately, I don't have a simple way to answer that, but to point you in the right direction: you'll want to look for techniques to handle "balanced braces", which will allow you to find the class you want and then capture everything from its first brace to its last. That done, then you can recursively search again within the class for additional classes, pulling out the nested classes as you find them. I'm sorry I don't know much about Roslyn at this point, as that probably is an excellent way to go.

Comment: Thanks peter for your Valuable Suggestion  .. . i am going to figure it out .